# Which journals accept articles already out as preprints?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, preprint

I want to send our preprint, that we put online around three months ago, to a journal. How can I know which journals accept articles previously put online as a preprint? Many of them do not mention this in their guidelines. Please do not tell me ask the editors, since in most of the journals editors do not answer or take a very long time to answer!

Comment: If it was already published, why do you need a preprint? And, sorry, but only the journal can answer for itself.

Comment: It was not published!! preprint is not peer reviewed! I do not need pre print! Do you know what preprint means?

Comment: What was published 3 months ago?

Comment: @AhmadTurani I do think Buffy likely unintentionally changed the meaning of your question by trying to clarify it; please use the [edit] to improve the question yourself and make it more clear. Note your original said "I want to send our priprint which **was published** around3 months ago", bold mine. If you only have a preprint, not published, why say published?

Comment: @AhmadTurani The term published is ambiguous these days.  Posting on a preprint repository is technically publishing, but most academics just say a preprint was posted.

Answer (score 2):

There's typically no policy against submitting preprints (since most submissions are preprints), so the answer is "all of them".

Comment: Yes but a few journals I saw, is against it.

Comment: @AhmadTurani really? Can you give an example?